# TLS in Java fails with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Exception message: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jks, truststore

I've seen some similar threads but None of them helped me.
I generate new key pair for the server using command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias test-tls-server -keystore TestServerKeyStore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA -validity 365
```

I export servers certificate to cer file:

```
keytool -export -alias test-tls-server -file test_server.cer -keystore TestServerKeyStore.jks
```

I create client key store using command:

```
keytool -import -keystore TestClientKeyStore.jks -storetype JKS -alias test-tls-server -file test_server.cer
```

Note that the certificate is self-signed purposely.

I also configure locations and passwords for keystores on both sides:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", <path_to_keystore_file>);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", <pass_to_keystore>);
```

When I try to connect to server, on client side everything looks OK until I try to read something from the socket.
On server side I get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Exception message: Received fatal
> alert: bad_certificate

This code worked for previous certificate but since it expired I need to generate the new one. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `keytool -import` command needs `-trustcacerts`.

Comment: @user207421: not when the cert isn't issued by a known CA. OP: you need to create a keystore-format file on the client containing the cert, but use it as _truststore_ in the protocol. I.e. if your application uses JSSE defaults, **on client configure sysprops `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*`** not `keyStore*`. (On server do use `keyStore*` and the original file that contains the privatekey as well as the cert.)